# I dont understand these errors (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here, i provide some code and a picture of the errors. Hope someone can help.

[image: code]

[image: error]

Comment: I dont understand what i need to do. When i go on edit on unity, i cant find settings, same on visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

[this might help as well](https://forum.unity.com/threads/input-axis-mousex-is-not-setup.120321/)

Try "Mouse X" and "Mouse Y" because that is what that axes are by default

To change or add input go to: edit-> project settings -> input manager, and you can change setting there

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

It literally says in the error that you have to go to "Edit -> Settings -> Input" to check what all your accessible Inputs are.

As RIVERMAN2010 wrote you might just spelled it incorrect. In case that's not the error you still can go to the Input settings and look up what Inputs you have or set a new Input up if you need to.